# Decrease the size of right click menu

Tags: menu, windows-10, size, right-click

[This image is showing the size of my right click menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDxGA.jpg)

Basically, it is changed, I don't know how so I just want to decrease its size and restore to default. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the "Open command window here as administrator" part might be the source of your problem. Search your registry for that string and rename or remove the parts you don't need.